# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable; incorrect syntax

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am receiving a TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in a script I am building.

[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hpgb.png)

Given that this is a get request for a url, what would be the proper syntax to print the results from the URL?

I am attempting to retrieve a list of exports from the api https://developers.encoura.org/

```py
import requests

session_token = "X"
headers = {"x-API-key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Authorization":"X",
            "Organization":"X",}

#URL = https://api-datalab.encoura.org/v1
data = {
    "userName": "xxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxx",
    "acceptedTerms": True
    }

#Get list of files
get_exports = {"status": "NotDelivered", "productKey": "score-reporter"}

r = requests.get("https://api-datalab.encoura.org/v1/datacenter/exports", auth= [headers], params= [get_exports])
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full traceback as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think you need to put `headers` in a list. Same might be true of `get_exports`

Comment: Try `r = requests.get("https://api-datalab.encoura.org/v1/datacenter/exports", auth=headers, params=get_exports)`

Comment: `auth` is for a (user,password) basic authentication tuple.  Use `headers=headers`.  See [the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#module-requests)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues here. You need to fix your auth setup and you to correct your usage of the keyword arguments in your `get` call.

#### Fixing your auth

Checking out the Swagger docs you included in your question, it looks like there's a `login` route that you need to `post` to authenticate with the API. If successful, you'll get a session token that proves you're logged in. Using that, you can create the headers you need to log in.

```py
import requests

data = {
    "userName": "xxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxx",
    "acceptedTerms": True
}

login_res = requests.post("https://api-datalab.encoura.org/v1/login", body=data)

res_body = login_res.json()

# Note: case matters!
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {res_body.sessionToken}",
    "x-api-key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Organization":"X"
}
```

#### Fixing your syntax

You're passing your `kwargs` as lists, but they should be dictionaries [per the requests documentation.](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/)

```py
# ...
requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=get_exports)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for reaching out! I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to build this script with little-to-no knowledge. I was able to successfully login and authenticate using a script that I built, and received a 200 response and key. However, since revising the script above the get request, I'm now receiving a {"status":401,"message":"Missing Authorization Header"} message when running the script. What am I missing  here?

Comment: @sdgibbs your error is likely from a malformatted Authorization header. Make sure it looks just like the one in my answer (i.e. starts with "Bearer " and then has the token value). That syntax I use is called [f-string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and it lets you use variables' values inside a string.

Comment: I've also updated my answer to demonstrate how to correctly access the response body after making the login request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for chiming in. I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to build this script with little-to-no knowledge based on what I've learned with Visual Studio.

The document I am referencing is here and includes detail of what should be included in the header, which I believe I had: https://helpcenter.encoura.org/hc/en-us/article_attachments/20370572326029

I was able to successfully login and authenticate using a script that I built, and received a 200 response and key. However, since revising the script above the get request, I'm now receiving a {"status":401,"message":"Missing Authorization Header"} message when running the script. What am I missing here?

````
import requests

session_token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IkRWc3NEMkljSmRmUFdpUjZkc3dKUSJ9.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.HrT5Z724jqpJmZrwPW7YBerfNX3jfZTCTrX6qUGX9_FR6_hgzxvpavK-BLZeAGCrhhLnRBvWO17lkXkKd7JxjiIP_4QIgufpuFQPy9-jLqPF43iLW8X2u_7zNM4KwjR6zGyKy0Zd67x-SkueslYRWNfdgxwbPYFvh-GIBYTrY3TwEGig0F7MHgSUt5c9nDbySRpjHahGI74L7ZNq90ahsNGO1duc3V5G11ZCJZHUEF0zjizkymOzaSsD7Dg6UGPPaywV3ogNrXSxKTR6hZGD_kLRWWfvErvCF1J1V925CDGiGFTzYZy_avDQTgYAj4WEwyJQ8qQxfdx1nLgzqZMc_Q"
headers = {"x-API-key":"mFzAJRWYTO1W9SwQ2rcSm3mQUh9byKcf3jNwbngL",
            "Authorization":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IkRWc3NEMkljSmRmUFdpUjZkc3dKUSJ9.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.HrT5Z724jqpJmZrwPW7YBerfNX3jfZTCTrX6qUGX9_FR6_hgzxvpavK-BLZeAGCrhhLnRBvWO17lkXkKd7JxjiIP_4QIgufpuFQPy9-jLqPF43iLW8X2u_7zNM4KwjR6zGyKy0Zd67x-SkueslYRWNfdgxwbPYFvh-GIBYTrY3TwEGig0F7MHgSUt5c9nDbySRpjHahGI74L7ZNq90ahsNGO1duc3V5G11ZCJZHUEF0zjizkymOzaSsD7Dg6UGPPaywV3ogNrXSxKTR6hZGD_kLRWWfvErvCF1J1V925CDGiGFTzYZy_avDQTgYAj4WEwyJQ8qQxfdx1nLgzqZMc_Q",
            "Organization":"d1e01227-404d-439a-b7e8-12cfd11a6863",
              }

#URL = https://api-datalab.encoura.org/v1
data = {
    "userName": "Username",
    "password": "Password",
    "acceptedTerms": True
    }

# Get list of files
get_exports = {"status": "NotDelivered", "productKey": "score-reporter"}



r = requests.get("https://api-datalab.encoura.org/v1/datacenter/exports", headers=headers, params=get_exports)
print(r.text)```
````